# What does philosophy have to do with category theory?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, category-theory

Category theory seems very abstract and unrelated to philosophy. Why does it seem to be a part of philosophy? Is category theory used in philosophy and in the development of logical arguments? Isn't it a mathematical topic?

**What does philosophy have to do with category theory?**

Comment: You are aware, I hope that "category" has two very different meanings in philosophy. One is the mathematical structures of category theory and another is in logic where "category" is used in a sense must closer to its normal meaning: a class of things related by some property.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. I'm not sure why a clarificatory question about the interplay between category theory and philosophy isn't a good fit? The OP is feel to roll back the proposed edit.

Comment: @jd, I didn't vote to close for it not being related to philosophy but for being unfocused. Why is probability used in philosophy? Why is mereology used in philosophy? Why is geometry used in philosophy? Why is model theory used in philosophy? There is no single answer just like there is no single answer for why arithmetic is used in physics. People use the formalism that they find most effective for the purpose.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Thanks for the clarification. Seems a fair criticism.

Answer (score 1):

A good point-of-entry here is the SEP article on category theory, specifically the section [on its philosophical significance](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/#PhilSign):

> Category theory challenges philosophers in two ways, which are not necessarily mutually exclusive. On the one hand, it is certainly the task of philosophy to clarify the general epistemological and ontological status of categories and categorical methods, both in the practice of mathematics and in the foundational landscape. On the other hand, philosophers and philosophical logicians can employ category theory and categorical logic to explore philosophical and logical problems. ... Category theory also bears on more general philosophical questions. From the foregoing disussion, it should be obvious that category theory and categorical logic ought to have an impact on almost all issues arising in philosophy of logic: from the nature of identity criteria to the question of alternative logics, category theory always sheds a new light on these topics. Similar remarks can be made when we turn to ontology, in particular formal ontology: the part/whole relation, boundaries of systems, ideas of space, etc. Ellerman (1988) has bravely attempted to show that category theory constitutes a theory of universals, one having properties radically different from set theory, which is also seen as a theory of universals. Moving from ontology to cognitive science, MacNamara & Reyes (1994) have tried to employ categorical logic to provide a different logic of reference. In particular, they have attempted to clarify the relationships between count nouns and mass terms. Other researchers are using category theory to study complex systems, cognitive neural networks, and analogies. (See, for instance, Ehresmann 2018, Ehresmann & Vanbremeersch 1987, 2007, Healy 2000, Healy & Caudell 2006, Arzi-Gonczarowski 1999, Brown & Porter 2006.) Finally, philosophers of science have turned to category theory to shed a new light on issues related to structuralism in science. (See, for instance, Brading & Landry 2006, Bain 2013, Lam & Wüthrich 2015, Eva 2016, Lal & Teh 2017, Landry 2007, 2012, 2018.)

Peterson[[14](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570868314000573)] is a look at grounding a deontic logic (for a specific national legal system) in category-theoretic language. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) features many entries pertaining to philosophy, e.g. [this brief survey of Hegel](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Georg+Hegel). Bertato[[23](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-42127-3_22)] approaches the quixotic logic of the Trinity concept using category theory (that this enterprise counts as (at least obliquely) philosophical can be seen from the fact that there are entries on the Trinity in both [the IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/trinity/) and [the SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/trinity/)). Doubtless many more examples can be adduced from combing through Google results for {"category theory" "philosophy"}, and I will leave such as an exercise for the OP poster :)

Comment: +1 "I will leave such as an exercise for..." lol Someone has read a textbook or two.

Comment: I ask you to vote to reopen. I'm not sure what the basis for closure is, but it seems a rather salient question?

Comment: @JD I myself didn't VTC but if the OP can flesh out their query a little I will definitely VTR!

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> What does philosophy have to do with category theory?

Kristian Berry has answered in the particular about [category theory (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/), but I'm going to respond to the question in the slightly larger context of category theory as one of many models in philosophy. **It aids philosophy of language by providing a [formal semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_semantics_(natural_language)) and is an object of study as such.** From SEP:

> Category theory has come to occupy a central position in contemporary mathematics and theoretical computer science, and is also applied to mathematical physics... Category theory is both an interesting object of philosophical study, and a potentially powerful formal tool for philosophical investigations of concepts such as space, system, and even truth. It can be applied to the study of logical systems in which case category theory is called “categorical doctrines” at the syntactic, proof-theoretic, and semantic levels... it raises many issues about mathematical ontology and epistemology.

First, if you are not aware, the [philosophy of mathematics (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/) is a sub-discipline of philosophy, and **category theory plays a prominent role in because it is part of a proposed framework for a [foundation of s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics)**. From the SEP article on the philosophy of mathematics:

> Lawvere from early on promoted the idea that a category of categories could be used as a foundational framework. (See Lawvere 1964, 1966.) This proposal now rests in part on the development of higher-dimensional categories, also called weak n-categories. (See, for instance Makkai 1998.) The advent of topos theory in the seventies brought new possibilities. Mac Lane has suggested that certain toposes be considered as a genuine foundation for mathematics. (See Mac Lane 1986.) Lambek proposed the so-called free topos as the best possible framework, in the sense that mathematicians with different philosophical outlooks might nonetheless agree to adopt it. (See Couture & Lambek 1991, 1992, Lambek 1994.)

Lastly, let us consider it's relationship to a major philosophical invention, the Curry-Howard Correspondence which posits there are isomorphisms between different parts of systems of formal semantics. Thus, **it is also been linked to the [Curry-Howard Correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)**. From WP:

> It is a generalization of a syntactic analogy between systems of formal logic and computational calculi that was first discovered by the American mathematician Haskell Curry and the logician William Alvin Howard.[1](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/) It is the link between logic and computation that is usually attributed to Curry and Howard, although the idea is related to the operational interpretation of intuitionistic logic given in various formulations by L. E. J. Brouwer, Arend Heyting and Andrey Kolmogorov (see Brouwer–Heyting–Kolmogorov interpretation)[3](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/) and Stephen Kleene (see Realizability). The relationship has been extended to include category theory as the three-way Curry–Howard–Lambek correspondence.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)

On the whole, of course, these sorts of issues apply to a specific flavor of philosophy, [post-linguistic-turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_turn) [analytical philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy). Thus, it is of strong interest in philosophy to those who have a certain intense focus on mathematics, language, and computation and an education in the formalisms such as proof and model theory, set theory, type theory, the formal semantics of natural language, and formalisms in computation. Many people interested in philosophy eschew such an esoteric philosophy because of generalist interests, of expertise in other sorts of philosophy such as Continental, Indian, historical, or meta-philosophy. [On this view, category theory is just another field of mathematics and may seem far removed from the pursuit of wisdom in the traditional sense.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wished to know, that category theory is employed to study logic and philosophy.; as it is mentioned in paragraph 3 of plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory. I had also come into the Curry-Howard corresspondence before.

Comment: @ale_7 I thought so. Don't take the closure personally! :D Good luck.

Comment: I don't, thank you!